D3.min.js Installation Issues
I am using Scott Murray's book to learn about D3.  In "Chapter 4 Setup"/"Download D3"  the instruction is to go to https://d3js.org and click the download button.  I am not finding the Download button.  I have downloaded from other sites but when I unzip I do not find d3.min.js or d3.js.
Please point me to a writeup so that I can get this done.  Thanks!

Method: 1
Here's a simpler way to include D3.js using a CDN link:
i. Open your HTML file.
ii. Add this line inside the <head> section or just before the closing </body> tag:
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

Your HTML file will look like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Project Title</title>
    <!-- Add D3.js here -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your content goes here -->

    <!-- Or add D3.js here -->
    <!-- <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>

Method: 2
Here’s how you can install D3.js with npm in a simple way:
i. Open your terminal or command prompt.
ii. Run this command:
npm install d3

iii. In your JavaScript file, use D3 by adding this line:
import * as d3 from 'd3';

Method: 3
ObservableHQ provides an interactive environment for working with D3.js and other JavaScript libraries. Here’s how you can create a D3 visualization using an Observable notebook:
Steps to Use ObservableHQ for D3.js
i. Create an ObservableHQ Account:
[https://observablehq.com/][1]
Go to ObservableHQ and sign up or log in with your GitHub account.
ii. Create a New Notebook:
Once logged in, click on the "New Notebook" button to create a new notebook.
iii. Set Up Your Notebook:
In the new notebook, you can start writing JavaScript code directly. Observable notebooks are reactive, meaning that cells can automatically update based on changes to other cells.
iv. Import D3.js:
You don't need to manually import D3.js in Observable, as it provides built-in support for D3.js. However, if you want to specify a version or use specific modules, you can import them as follows:
import { select, scaleLinear, axisBottom, axisLeft } from "d3@7";

